# Pre-requisites for Canadian PNP

Tags: immigration, canada

Must I have a Job Offer or Canadian full-time education before applying for PNP?

Comment: Have you checked using their eligibility tool? https://www.canadavisa.com/assess/mobile/landing.html?site=cv&cat=pnpland#gs.nba4sq

Comment: It is confusing they don't specify clearly whether I would require or not.

Comment: It depends on the province. You'll have to check each one. https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/provincial-nominees/eligibility.html

Comment: @mkennedy Thanks for the link, that's an answer.

Comment: @paul link-only answers are frowned upon. Your question is really too broad anyway.

Comment: Oh really? I assumed that it answered my question. How my question is too broad? I mean obviously there are more pre-requisites but I am only asking about having a job offer or Canadian Education in advance before applying for PNP.